# default a dependent picklist value if there is only one value

Tags: dependent-picklist, configuration

how can i default a dependent picklist value if there is only one value?

for example, i have controlling picklist value of A,B,C and dependent picklist value of 1,2,3,6,7,8

A - 1,2,3
B - 6
C - 7,8

so when i select B my dependent picklist will automatically show 6 instead of 'None' and need to choose again since there is only one value there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it doesn't match with your business requirements but if you would make the dependant picklist field required (on the page layout), it will set by default the selection if there is only one option.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value for the dependent picklist by Workflow Field Update in that case. It won't show on the page layout during record edit, though.